# Date referencing in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to have a date referencing month after month without having to change it. For example, I want to return January as a result in a formula entered in February that won't change when March comes. January stays as is. Tried the month -1 formula but I think it will change when the month changes?

Comment: Welcome.This can't be done with a formula since it will always be dynamic. If this is a one off event, you could manual copy/paste the cell, or write a macro/script to do the same.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Does this have to be done with a formula, or is an Apps Script function with a trigger acceptable?